# Error in accessing element in anonymous function in ajax program

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, function

I am trying to fetch data from file using ajax on mouseover. Everything works fine, except when I try to access a `<p>` element inside an anonymous function, I get nothing. Possible reason is that the element lost scope inside anonymous function. Please advise if you see a possible solution.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MouseOver Effect And Ajax </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/study/libraries/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var xhr=false;
                initAll();

                $('div.pcard').mouseover(function(){
                    if(xhr)
                    { 
                        var pname=$(this).children('p.pname').text();
                        var pname=pname+"_details.txt";
                        xhr.open("GET",pname);;
                        xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                            if(xhr.readyState==4)
                            { 
                                if(xhr.status==200)
                                { 
                                $(this).children('p.pdesc').text(""+msg);

                                alert($(this).children('p.pname').text());

                                $(this).children('p.pdesc').css({'visibility':'visible'});
                                }
                            }
                        }.bind(this);
                        xhr.send(null);
                    }
                });

                $('div.pcard').mouseout(function(){
                    $(this).children('p.pdesc').css({'visibility':'hidden'});   
                });


                function initAll()
                { 
                    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    { 
                        xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    else if(window.ActiveXObject)
                    { 
                        try{
                            xhr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }catch(e){}
                    }
                }


            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Interactive MouseOver</h2>
        <div id="products">
            <div class="pcard">
                <p class="pname">Sandwhiches</p>
                <p class="pdesc"></p>           
            </div>
            <div class="pcard">
                <p class="pname">Pizzas</p>
                <p class="pdesc"></p>           
            </div>
            <div class="pcard">
                <p class="pname">Soups</p>
                <p class="pdesc"></p>           
            </div>
            <p style="clear:both"></p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe you can tell us where the problem is

Comment: And why are you sharing one XMLHttpRequest for all AJAX calls? Why not create a new one in each mouseover? I don't know what happens when you try to send an XMLHttpRequest when it's already been sent or in the process of sending/getting the response.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you don't use `.bind(this)` and instead use the solution of storing `this` before your `onreadystatechange` and then reference that variable?

Comment: @Ian: A single XHR object can handle multiple concurrent requests, but in this code, the requests are synchronous, so the UI should freeze anyway until the response comes back. Overall, there's something rather hideous about sending  XHR requests in response to `mouseover` events IMO.

Comment: @user1689607 So the requests are synchronous because the same XMLHttpRequest is being used? Either way, I agree, I'm scared of the point of this

Comment: @Ian: No, they're synchronous because `true` was not passed as the third argument to `.open()`. If `true` was given, they would be async... but then the `onreadystatechange` handler would be overwritten with every concurrent request, which means only the latest bound version would be invoked when a request returns. Also, I don't see any `msg` variable declared in the code *(which is used in the handler)*. ...Yeah, I'm not feeling too compelled to touch this one.

Comment: @user1689607 On MDN, the spec for the `open` function says that parameter "An optional boolean parameter, defaulting to true, indicating whether or not to perform the operation asynchronously."...that's why I was confused on what you meant...by default, it's asynchronous. But yeah, as async, it makes it even more messy.

Comment: @Ian: You're right. I was remembering it incorrectly. The default is `true`, which would make these asynchronous and overall a big mess. :) But making a local XHR variable in the event handler would certainly help things,

Comment: ...also, it looks like calling `.open()` on an already active XHR will abort the current request. It's calling `.send()` multiple times that's allowed.

Comment: @user1689607 Haha I was second guessing myself anyways...I know jQuery defaults it to true, so I wouldn't be surprised if it was the opposite for native Javascript.

Comment: @user1689607 Interesting, wouldn't have thought that was a spec, but that's good to know. I guess the conclusion we can make is that it is not organized overall in a good way, and a temporary solution to test is making a separate XMLHttpRequest for every `mouseover`...sharing one does not seem to be a solution, at least not with the current organization.

Comment: @Ian: Agreed. You should post an answer. I'm too lazy today.

Comment: @user1689607 Haha oh laziness. I'll post something, not sure how "helpful" it'll be to the OP

Answer (score 1):

Us commenters have concluded that sharing one `XMLHttpRequest` is not a good idea and you would probably want to fire off a new one for every `mouseover` event occurring. Things can get messy when you call `open` on an already opened/uncompleted request, while `send` should be okay. What is normally done is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.pcard').mouseover(function () {
        var self = $(this);

        var pname = self.children('p.pname').text();
        var pname = pname + "_details.txt";

        var xhr = ajaxFunction();
        xhr.open("GET", pname);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    var msg = "" + xhr.responseText;

                    self.children('p.pdesc').text(""+msg);

                    //alert(self.children('p.pname').text());

                    self.children('p.pdesc').css({'visibility':'visible'});
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(null);
    });

    $('div.pcard').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).children('p.pdesc').css({'visibility':'hidden'});   
    });
});

function ajaxFunction() {
    var ajaxRequest; // The variable that makes Ajax possible!
    try {
        // Firefox, Chrome, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                try {
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
                    } catch (e) {
                        throw new Error("This browser does not support XMLHttpRequest.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ajaxRequest;
}
```

In the `ajaxFunction`, I'm not sure if you really have to go past the first 2 ActiveXObject attempts, that's just something I've seen...and there's several more you can "try" for. There were a few other things that were weird in your original code (that was edited by others without looking) - you commented out the line that set the `msg` variable, and then you tried to use it on the next line. The `.bind` probably works, but I like the way I provided...that's up to you...try both and see if either one works separately.

But as the other answer already points out, if you're already using jQuery, why not use `$.ajax`?

Comment: Forgot about this question for a while. +1 for not being lazy. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have jquery, why are you rewriting your own ajax call?

Save the this into a local variable : `var that = this` then you can reuse it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.pcard').mouseover(function(){

    var pname=$(this).children('p.pname').text();
    pname=pname+"_details.txt";
    var that = this; /// keeping the scope
    $.ajax({
       url:pname,
       success: function () {
           $(that).children('p.pdesc').text(""+msg);
           alert($(that).children('p.pname').text());
           $(that).children('p.pdesc').css({'visibility':'visible'});

       }
    });
});
```

Comment: FWIW, if you're going to use `$.ajax`, it's cleaner to add a `context: this,` property to the call than to do `var that = this;` in the enclosing scope.